# How to read data from /dev/xxxx?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am recently working on a project to read and write data on a kernel module. I have created a C language application to read and write data (char data) on kernel module. Also I can write data using

```
echo hello > /dev/xxxx
```

How can I read back my stored data without C language code? Can I use something like this?

```
cat /dev/xxxx
```

when I use this, I get a segmentation fault.

```
read value </dev/xxxx
```

when I use this, dmesg shows that kernel module keep running read function forever.

```
[root@zzzz TUNNEL_EXCHANGE]# echo hello > /dev/xxxx 
yyyy: device opened
yyyy: call for write
yyyy: Value written
yyyy: device released
[root@zzzz TUNNEL_EXCHANGE]# line=$(head -n 1 /dev/xxxx)
yyyy: device opened
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address af001000
pgd = eead0000
[af001000] *pgd=3e8eb811, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops - BUG: 7 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: xxxx_driver(PO)
CPU: 0 PID: 927 Comm: head Tainted: P           O    4.6.0-xilinx #1
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
task: eeb03600 ti: ee940000 task.ti: ee940000
PC is at __copy_to_user_std+0x4c/0x3c4
LR is at 0x0
pc : [<b02c051c>]    lr : [<00000000>]    psr: 20070013
sp : ee941ecc  ip : 00000000  fp : 00000000
r10: 00000000  r9 : ee940000  r8 : 00000000
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00000000  r5 : 00000000  r4 : 00000000
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 000015c0  r1 : af001000  r0 : aeeb2524
Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c5387d  Table: 3ead006a  DAC: 00000055
Process head (pid: 927, stack limit = 0xee940210)
Stack: (0xee941ecc to 0xee942000)
1ec0:                            ee941f88 00000051 00002000 b0106f04 aeeb1b64
1ee0: 00002000 00000000 00002000 af000140 aeeb1b64 af0000ec ee941f88 b01c3544
1f00: aeeb3fbd 0002817d 00000000 b0101274 00001000 00000000 00000000 00001000
1f20: 00000003 ee9be680 ef31e700 00000003 00000000 ef31e740 00000000 ee932d80
1f40: ee941f88 00002000 aeeb1b64 aeeb1b64 ee932d80 ee941f88 00002000 b01c411c
1f60: ee932d80 aeeb1b64 00002000 ee932d80 ee932d80 aeeb1b64 00002000 b0106f04
1f80: ee940000 b01c4cac 00000000 00000000 00002000 00002000 7fffe000 00000001
1fa0: 00000003 b0106d40 00002000 7fffe000 00000003 aeeb1b64 00002000 77a94100
1fc0: 00002000 7fffe000 00000001 00000003 00000003 aeeb3fbd 0002817d 00000000
1fe0: 00000000 aeeb1ad4 000150a8 a6f32890 60070010 00000003 00000000 00000000
[<b02c051c>] (__copy_to_user_std) from [<af000140>] (xxxx_read+0x54/0x8c [xxxx_driver])
[<af000140>] (xxxx_read [xxxx_driver]) from [<b01c3544>] (__vfs_read+0x1c/0xcc)
[<b01c3544>] (__vfs_read) from [<b01c411c>] (vfs_read+0x84/0xec)
[<b01c411c>] (vfs_read) from [<b01c4cac>] (SyS_read+0x3c/0x74)
[<b01c4cac>] (SyS_read) from [<b0106d40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x3c)
Code: ba000002 f5d1f03c f5d1f05c f5d1f07c (e8b151f8) 
---[ end trace c5d8c90d390bee96 ]---
yyyy: device released
[root@zzzz TUNNEL_EXCHANGE]# echo  $line 

[root@zzzz TUNNEL_EXCHANGE]#
```

This is the Kernel driver code read function

```
static ssize_t xxxx_read(struct file *file, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "xxxx: call for read\n");
    //if(xxxx_str != NULL && count != 0 && count < TEXTLENGTH ){
            if(copy_to_user(buf, xxxx_str, count))
                    return -EINVAL; 
        *ppos = count;
        printk(KERN_ALERT "xxxx: Value Read\n");
        return count;
    //}
    //printk(KERN_ALERT "xxxx: Value Not Read\n");
    //return 1;
}
```

This work fine with `open, write, read, close` systems calls by C language.

Comment: if you get *segmentation fault* from `cat /dev/xxxx` I am pretty sure your *module* is *badly broken*.

Comment: `dd` provides most flexible interface for reading devices from command-line, i.e. `dd if=/dev/xxxx bs=1 count=1 | od -c` will read single character from device.

Comment: I have update the post with my output. With the `cat /dev/xxxx` also give the same error. This errors are shown in `dmesg`.

Comment: I gives something, thank you :)

`[root@zzzz TUNNEL_EXCHANGE]# dd if=/dev/xxxx bs=1 count=1 | od -c
xxxx: device opened
xxxx: Value Read

xxxx: device released

1+0 records in

1+0 records out

1 byte copied, 0.0107191 s, 0.1 kB/s

0000000   h

0000001

[root@zzzz TUNNEL_EXCHANGE]# 
`

Comment: There is a bug in your kernel module. We can't tell you anything more than that without the code.

Comment: sec. I will add it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `read` function implementation is broken:

1. You don't check if `count` is too big. In that case you should only copy as many bytes as are available.
2. You don't use the value of the current file position, which will give strange results in case of multiple reads.

As a result of the combination of the above, your function also has no way to signal end of file (by returning 0 when there is no more data). So if your code doesn't crash due to #1, it's likely to loop forever.

Comment: After adding `return 0`, it stopped looping thing. But after removing the commented if condition, to check the length of `count`, it started to not to go to if condition, which has `coppy_to_user()`. Therefore, `cat /dev/xxxx` does not give any value. and `read mydata < /dev/xxxx` seems like read the value. but `echo $mydata` shows no value. Thank you for the tip. :)

Comment: @Champika Your if condition is not enough - you need to return as many bytes as are available (up to `count`). I suggest looking at books or tutorials about writing kernel modules.